# Portable software tool to pipe sound output to microphone input

Tags: software-rec, audio

Are there any portable tools for directing sound output straight back in as microphone input?

**EDIT** I would prefer that it be software as apposed to hardware (a wire).

Comment: Some audio cards have drivers whose sound mixer lets you choose audio-out (e.g. "wave-out mix") as an input! I find a line-out to line-in audio cable to be pretty portable but that would be off-topic :-)

Comment: A cable from Radio Shack?  You can get one with a built-in attenuator to reduce the level so that the output doesn't overdrive the mike input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) is a paid one I use and it works very well, it is the gold standard and it has been around since Win98 and it works all the way up to windows 7. It has a demo to try it out, but if you don't pay for it every so often it will say "Trial" over the output.

Also note (per the VAC page) you may already have the ability to do this with your stock windows drivers. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/) on how to check to see if it is available for you on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Are [these](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=3.5mm%20male%20-female&_sop=15) portable enough?